# get last value form ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have connected two tables "Status" and Service" with ManyToMany and I get all entries with the following field:
`yield ArrayField::new('lastStatus', 'Last Status')`

But I would like to display only the last element.
I tried it with end() but it tells me that it is not an array.
What format is it and how can I manipulate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Arleigh Hix
I have found the following solution

```
# src/Entity/Service.php
    public function getLastStatus()
    {
        return $this->getStatuses()->last();
    }
```

`yield TextField::new('lastStatus', 'Last Status')`

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` and you can use the [`last` method](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html#last)